# Problem with displaying specific data in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I'm trying to create divs with specific values received from a getter in ts file. I'm using Vue.js

```js
filters: filters, 
    // e.g. [
    //        0: {filter: "filter1"}
    //        1: {filter: "filter2"}
    //        2: {filter: "filter3"}
    //        3: {filter: "filter4"}
    //      ]

values: values,
    // e.g. [
    //        0: {value: "11111"}
    //        1: {value: "22222"}
    //        2: {value: "33333"}
    //        3: {value: "44444"}
    //      ]
```

What I want to achieve is to display 4 divs and in each of them

```html
<div class="filters-value-wraper">
   <div v-for="(item, index) in filtersComponents()" class="filters-value">
      <div class="filter"> {{ item.filters.filter }}</div>
      <div class="values">{{ item.values.value }}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

All I can do is to display the whole filters/values array but I don't know how to "throw" another value from the array for each subsequent div. I mean for the first `value[0]` and `filter[0]` for the second `value[1]` and `filter[1]` etc.

Comment: Can you show `filtersComponents()`?  This `v-for` doesn't look right even if the `index` is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, it should be:

```html
<div class="filter"> {{ item.filters[index].filter }} </div>
<div class="values"> {{ item.values[index].value }} </div>
```

You use the `index` to access the array by index

Comment: It works! Can't believe that solution i so simple and I din't figure it out.

Thank you very much for your time :)